# Cast to unimplemented interface compiles

Tags: java, class, interface, reference

I am not sure I understand code on line 1 below?

```
interface Talkable{ }
class Device{}
class Phone extends Device implements Talkable{}


Talkable d = (Talkable) new Device(); //line 1
Talkable p = new Phone(); //line 2
```

I understand line2 since Phone implements Talkable, but Device and Talkable are unrelated, How can line1 be legal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, in Java it is *perfectly valid* to cast one *related type* to another (even if the casting makes little sense). You will get an error during runtime if the types are not *compatible*.

For example :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = (String) new Object();
        System.out.println(s.intern());

    }
```

Compiles fine but gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:5)` during runtime

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. So, are you saying even if Phone did Not extend Device, line one would still pass by the compiler?

Comment: Why does `(Number) ""` fail?

Comment: @August The compiler knows that a string cannot possibly be a `Number`. But a `Device` _might_ be a `Talkable`.

Comment: Up to a point. You can't cast between unrelated classes, for example.

Comment: No, it's because `String` is final and so no instance can possibly implement `Number`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

Comment: @AlanStokes Same thing applies for `class C1 {}`, `class C2{}`. `(C1) new C2()` will also fail.

Comment: @August I agree; I said so above.

Comment: @AlanStokes - Yes. You can't do that. `String s = (String) new FileOutputStream("abc.txt");` fails. I will have to go through the JLS again :)

Answer (score 18):

The reason the compiler accepts this is explained in the [JLS section 5.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) (relevant part in bold):

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> If S is a class type:
>
> - If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Furthermore, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types (§4.5), and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> - If T is an interface type:
>
>   - **If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.**
>
>     **Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might).**

In your case, a `java.lang.ClassCastException` will be thrown at runtime since `Device` cannot be converted to `Talkable`. But until the program executes, the compiler allows the cast because there may be a subclass of `Device` that implements `Talkable`.

Answer (score 6):

Line 1 will throw a runtime exception. The compiler does not check at compile time if the cast can succesfully be done. This is why it is sometimes advisable to check this first with the `instanceof` operator.

In general, you can always cast a variable `x` of type `A` to any interface `C`, because there may exist a class `B extends A implements C`, or a class `B implements A, C`

The same is not true for casting a variable `x` of class `A` to any class `D`, because there cannot exist a subclass `E extends A, D`, because a class may not extend multiple classes.

Answer (score 3):

Practically, on line one the code explicitly "tells" the compiler that the object on the right side is an object of type on the left side (this is called `type casting`). This is valid against any two types in Java in compile time, but if types are unrelated, there is going to be a runtime error (an `Exception` will be thrown).

On line two, what is done is valid in both compile time and runtime, because `Phone` is of whatever type it extends and/or implements, so practically, Phone is a `Talkable` (and a `Device`).